# Material-Ui How to adjust width to display items horizontally

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on kanban/Trello clone app with Material-Ui,
I tried to display columns horizontally and keep columns the same width.
All columns are displayed horizontally in the same row.
If display area for columns requires to extend browser width, the display area width is automatically adjusted.
The issue is Material UI doesn't allow me to display columns with side scroll.
If I decided the display area directly, like width:2000. the all columns displayed horizontally,
but there is always redundant space.
Because the width is fixed, and we don't know how many columns users create.
What is the solution for this issue?
these are the code I tried.

1/wrapped child with Grid

```
<Grid container style={{margin: 0,width: "100%"}}>
{children}
</Grid>
```

2/set style like this

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignContent: "center",
    width: 20000,
    overflowX: "auto"
  }
```

3/use Container and Grid

```
<Container className={classes.container}>
<Grid container direction='row' justify='flex-start' alignItems='flex-start'>
{children}
</Container >
</Grid >

onst useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignContent: "center"
    // width: 20000,
    // overflowX: "auto"
  },
  container: {
    overflowY: "scroll",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you put up a CodeSandbox showing your issue please ? Thanks.

Comment: Since this I needed to fix this issue urgently, I fixed this issue by not using the Material UI.